# Trying to open url in google chrome, but closes immediately after being launched with selenium

Tags: selenium

I tried to launch chrome with selenium. but as soon as the browser loads the urls, google chrome closes automatically. here is the code:

'''

```
from selenium import webdriver
url= 'https://www.gmail.com'
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get(url)
```

'''

Answer (score 1):

Because selenium4 no need to use driver.close()
method they automatically close the driver after execution. So `options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)` argument will help you to prevent to close immediately after once launch the url with google chrome

```
# selenium 4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

#chrome to stay open
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=options)
url= 'https://www.gmail.com'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
```